# Asp.net Div tags in a for loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, for-loop, nested

Is it possible to include div tags within a for loop in an asp.net page and assign its id dynamically so that I can refer a particular div tag with the assigned id in a jquery script. 
I want to do something like below.

```
@for(var i = 0; i < projectCountGlobal; i++) 
{
    <div id="i" > // id should be assigned dynamically
        <div id="ProjectImage">

        </div>

        <div id="ProjectName">

        </div>


        <div id="Experts">
           <div id="ExpertImage">

           </div>
           <div id="ExpertName">

           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i you can do this using following code snippet:

```
  $('.topopup').hover(function () {           
      for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          $('body').append('<div id=' + i + '>a</div>');
       }           
  })
```

// HTML code on page

```
<body>
   <a href="#" class="topopup">Click Here </a>
   <div id="toPopup" style="display:none;">
   <div id="popup_content">Rahul Deshmukh</div>
   <div id="backgroundPopup"></div>
   <div id="containerDiv"></div>
   </div>
</body>
```

here i am appending div inside body tag for this you need to add min.js also in your peoject folder
here "topopup" is a anchor tag and on the mouse over of this anchor tag, i am adding div inside body tag.

Comment: Rahul, it seems exactly what I was looking for. But this ddn't work for me even I added the min.js to my project folder.

Comment: what problem you are facing?

Answer (score 2):

From the snippet it seems like you are doing razor view so you can simply do like this,

```
    <div id="@i" >
```

that shall do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Furqan that did the trick.. Further is it possible to refer the inner div ids,  for an example ProjectName div tag  by 'ProjectName{@i}'?

Comment: Yes it is possible the same way, this is the beauty of razor to mix html and server side code. "ProjectName@i"

Comment: Hey I tried to access inner div 'Projectname@i" in the jquery code by $('#ProjectName'+i).html();
But it didn't work for me.

Comment: @Rameshi, did u check that project divs are created with concatenated values of 'i'?